# How to make dissappear the text in the textfield of 1st view controller when clicked on Logout button in 2nd view controller?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:   
[self.navigationController.viewControllers         
objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count -2] 
animated:YES];

}
```

This is my logout code in 2nd view controller, i want to remove text
    in login screen of user name and password when clicked on Logout 
    button.. Please can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate or NSNotification for this.

Delegate.

Lets you have two View Controller.. One is ViewController and other NextViewController and You want to logout from NextViewController and clear the text in ViewController.

Steps: In NextViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol clearTextField <NSObject>
-(void)clearTextFieldInPreviousController: (NSString *)string;

@end

@interface NextViewController : UIViewController
@property (assign,nonatomic) id delegate;

@end
```

In nextViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [_delegate clearTextFieldInPreviousController:@""];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:   
[self.navigationController.viewControllers         
objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count -2] 
animated:YES];

}
```

And In Your ViewController.m

```
-(void)clearTextFieldInPreviousController: (NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"Fired");
    self.label.text =@"";
}
```

// Note before going to next controller. You will have to set the delegate.

```
– (IBAction)goNextButtonAction:(id)sender {
    NextViewController *acontollerobject=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NVCSID"];

    acontollerobject.delegate=self; // protocol listener
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:acontollerobject animated:YES];
}
```

you can visit this link for [Demo Example](https://iostpoint.wordpress.com/2016/06/25/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achieve this.

1. Use delegation to pass message to 1st viewcontroller about the logout event from 2nd view controller and reset views in the passed message implementation.
2. I will suggest you to make 2nd view controller as rootViewController and not to keep the login view as part of navigation stack. You can show the login controller as a modal viewController over the 2nd View controller.

Comment: Thanks il will try that.